# how to "FIT" dataset iteratively which is large for memory using sklearn decomposition function like kernelpca

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a partial_fit method for KernelPCA in python. how to "FIT" dataset iteratively which is large for memory using sklearn decomposition function like kernelpca.

Comment: Does it help to use `RBFSampler`?

Comment: sorry m new to this. I just fit the mnist dataset iteratively . multiple fit objects were created. i want to combine these objects so that i can use it to predict the test data.

Comment: for i in range(strPt,trLen,batchSize):
 train4pca=train[strPt:endPt]
 tempKernelpca = KernelPCA(n_components=n_components).fit(train4pca)
 strPt=strPt+endPt
 endPt=endPt+batchSize

Comment: No, there is no such method. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA

Comment: If it doesn't have to be KernelPCA, you could use [IncrementalPCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html)